# Is there any option to get old parent after sorting using jquery ui draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm working on multiple list which uses `jquery ui draggable` the problem is i cant get the older parent after drag and drop. How could I make it?

Consider this following example. It has two lists.

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

now the jquery ui sortable code is...

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
      start: function(event, ui) {},
      stop: function(event, ui) {},
      sort: function(event, ui) {},
      receive: function(event, ui) {},
      click: function(event, elem) {},
      mousedown: function(event, elem) {}
    }).disableSelection();
  });
  </script>
```

It has start(), stop(), sort(),receive(),click() & mousedown() but if we drag an item and drop in another list, we cant get the old parent of the item drag and dropped. no function is providing that option including start().

It is possible to find parent, if we juzz use two lists. But i want to work with multiple lists, so it becomes a serious trouble for me..

So please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need `sender` under event `change`

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-change